# How do I map an array of objects with react

Tags: reactjs

This is the Array I'm trying to map

```
const arr = [
{"title" : "something",
 "Text" : "something"
},
{"title" : "something",
 "Text" : "something"
},
{"title" : "something",
 "Text" : "something"
}
```

]

Tried to map it like this

```
{arr.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
         <p>{item.title}</p>
         <p>{item.Text}</p> 
         <button>
           click here 
         </button>
      </div>
    )
})}
```

It won't work so what am i missing here?

*edited**

Comment: `item.text` should be `item.Text` and `Const` should be `const`

Answer (score 3):

Why your Const is capital, it should be const and item.text should be item.Text

```js
const arr = [
{
 "title" : "something",
 "Text" : "something"
},
{"title" : "something",
 "Text" : "something"
},
{"title" : "something",
 "Text" : "something"
}
]

{arr.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
         <p>{item.title}</p>
         <p>{item.Text}</p> 
         <button>
           click here 
         </button>
      </div>
    )
})}
```

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/) might add value to the above code-snippet.

Comment: Sry wrote it wrong... So this should work right with the corrections

Answer (score 3):

Const needs to be lowercase

```
const arr = [
 { 
   "title" : "something",
   "Text" : "something"
 },
 {
   "title" : "something",
   "Text" : "something"
 },
 {
   "title" : "something",
   "Text" : "something"
 }
];
```

The Title key in you object is catitalized

```
{arr.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
         <p>{item.title}</p>
         <p>{item.Text}</p> 
         <button>
           click here 
         </button>
      </div>
    )
})}
```

Or you also can do it like this

```
{arr.map(({title, Text}, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
         <p>{title}</p>
         <p>{Text}</p> 
         <button>
           click here 
         </button>
      </div>
    )
})}
```